# Is it possible to take static files that "npm run build" command generates and convert these files back into a project?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I have some static Javascript build files but no source code that generated those. The developer who worked previously on the problem is no longer available to answer to me.

Is it possible to debuild those files?

Comment: are the minified/ugified? If no then you have the source code in javascript

Comment: No, its not minified. Is there any method of getting that 1 file back into multiple files. Or the only way is to do it manually?

Comment: No. There is no way if you have just one file. But you can make changes in that one file.

Comment: Also , you can manully seperate the code in multiple files if you want

Answer (score 0):

Iam affraid there are no simple solutions, but maybe have a look at https://www.npmjs.com/package/debundle which might suit your needs.

Comment: Thanks! This is interesting project.